# Gaining weight by eating mustard seeds

Tags: nutrition, dermatology, weight

I want to increase my body weight and reduce my skin problems. At night, I put mustard seeds in a glass of water, and in the morning I crush them in a mixer grinder with that water and drink that.

Is it good for weight gain? Is there any another benefit if I drink this every morning?

When I searched on the internet, most website showed that mustard seeds reduce weight.

Comment: Could you explain what your skin problems look like and how you want to fix them by gaining weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look at the [nutrient values of mustard seeds](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/274) shows a high energy density, with lots of protein (26g per 100g) and lipids (36g per 100g), as well as minerals and vitamins. All of these may be of benefit. The high energy density would logically promote weight gain... if the quantities you ingest are significant. 
It is not possible to say if it will help you gain weight or get rid of skin problems without knowing what your diet looks like apart from this morning glas, what these skin problems are, etc.

Comment: really thank you friend  .Good information .